# What is the best way to decide which post performs best based on Facebook Ad Data? Below is the link attached containing the columns of Facebook Data

Tags: mathematical-statistics, dataset

I have Facebook data with the following columns. What is the best way to understand the best performing posts and what is the approach?

Since I am not able to define a response variable I am not sure if modeling would help.

Are there any statistical techniques that might be helpful? What is the general approach to deal with such data?

[image: dataset columns]

Comment: If you don't have a response variable, how do you know which posts performed well?

Comment: Hello, Exactly my question. Is there a way to interpret the performance of the post with the given columns without modeling?

Comment: Unless you have actual observations, no there is no way to determine "success"from independent variables alone, most notably because we have not specified what we mean by success. However, some of those variables might be reasonable proxies for successful posts, such as total reach or engaged users. Once you've picked your metric of success, then you can explore predictive models.